# Load image with Javascript when clicked

Tags: javascript

[image]

I am trying to do something similar to the image above, I am using Wordpress and I will build the HTML output with PHP but I need to load a larger image into the Big image slot when a thumbnail image is clicked.

I found a site pof.com that uses this method below but when I try it I get the error below.  Please help?

```
<script>
function B(strNewImage, caption) {
  document.images['MP'].src = strNewImage;
  document.getElementById("icaption").innerHTML = caption;
}
</script>

<img src="http://default_image.jpg" border="0" id="mp" name="MP">

<a href="javascript: B('image_2.jpg','test')"><img src="thumbnails/image_2.jpg" border="0"></a>
<a href="javascript: B('image_3.jpg','test')"><img src="thumbnails/image_3.jpg" border="0"></a>
<a href="javascript: B('image_4.jpg','test')"><img src="thumbnails/image_4.jpg" border="0"></a>
<a href="javascript: B('image_5.jpg','test')"><img src="thumbnails/image_5.jpg" border="0"></a>
```

ERROR:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: B is not defined
```

Comment: Can you provide a real page example? I tried your code in jsFiddle and it works.

Comment: @SamuelHapak: That is the only page I have right now, but it isn't working for me on Google Chrome or Firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is working, [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9qFMk/9/), it's all about where you defined `B` function. Or maybe It's not working beacuse of undefined type of script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function B(strNewImage, caption) {
  document.images['MP'].src = strNewImage;
  document.getElementById("icaption").innerHTML = caption;
}
</script>
```

Comment: great thanks, I want to eventually change it to use something like `date-image` with the path to the image but I wanted to get this working first

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap in

```
window.onload = function() {
...
}
```

If you have jQuery:

```
$(function(){
...
});
```

Or move the script to the bottom of the page.